# IFC Reader/Writer iOS

Tags: ios, revit-api, revit, ifc

We would like to be able to create an IFC reader for an iOS app we are building that will enable us to render the underlying BIM generated design.
We found a rather old and unsupported C++ sdk [here](https://github.com/cstb/ifc2x3-SDK) but it's not what we are looking for.

Anyone tried anything like this or has any inputs for us would be great!

We are trying to build an app similar to this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tekla-field3d/id868034113?mt=8

Comment: The IFC Exporter for Revit is open source, that might be of some help. However, the license may be an issue (GPL/LGPL) https://sourceforge.net/projects/ifcexporter/

Answer (score 1):

The [Autodesk Viewer](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/) is based on WebGL and supported on multiple devices (including iOS). You can load your .IFC file (or files) and display without manipulating the file directly. See the complete [API documentation here](https://developer.autodesk.com/api/view-and-data-api/) and an [iOS sample here](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/workflow-ios-view.and.data.api).

Comment: Thanks Augusto. The iOS Sample using the A360 APIs did give me a good start. However, I was able to generate only a thumbnail out of it. Was unable to get the 3D view. Have you tried that ever?

Comment: If you see the thumbnail only, it means you accessed the auto-generated png image only. Probably using REST api. You are not starting the Javascript/html5 viewer. On iOS, you need to have a webview to achieve the 3d view, and this sample does not demo that part, it shows only how to translate the file.